# Square brackets in derivatives

Tags: derivatives, biology

I have two equations from the article "*Autopoiesis: a review and a reappraisal*" [[1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00114-002-0389-9)] that [attempt to] describe biological systems:

$$
\begin{align}
v_\mathrm{gen} &= \frac{d[s]}{dt}\label{eq:1}\tag{1}\\
v_\mathrm{dec} &= -\frac{d[s]}{dt}\label{eq:2}\tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

When $\eqref{eq:1}=\eqref{eq:2}$, then we have homeostasis.

When $\eqref{eq:1}>\eqref{eq:2}$, then we have growth.

When $\eqref{eq:1}<\eqref{eq:2}$, we have senescense.

What do the square brackets mean around $s$? This seems critically important to the overall claim of the equations because if this leads to a simple related rates problem, then that over-simplifies the definition of life. I would think $s$ would have to be a set of some chemical system or properties that would make the relation between $\eqref{eq:1}$ and $\eqref{eq:2}$ more complicated.

#### Reference

1. Luisi, P. L. *Naturwissenschaften* **2003,** *90* (2), 49–59. [DOI: 10.1007/s00114-002-0389-9](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00114-002-0389-9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[\mathrm{S}]$ is chemistry notation for the concentration of $\mathrm{S}$. So they're talking about the rate of change of concentrations of $\mathrm{S}$.

The notation is very sloppy in defining $v_\mathrm{gen}$ and $v_\mathrm{dec}$, though. $v_\mathrm{gen}$ is the rate of change of concentration in some reaction $\mathrm{A \to S}$ and $v_\mathrm{dec}$ is the negative rate of change in some reaction $\mathrm{S \to P}$.

There's a little bit of an explanation in [this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=1Oxfq5VTcDkC&lpg=PA161&ots=dfolQBp70X&dq=the%20minimal%20autopoietic%20system%20d%5BS%5D&pg=PA161#v=onepage&q=the%20minimal%20autopoietic%20system%20d%5BS%5D&f=false) about what's going on, on pages 161 and 162.

Comment: Yeah I agree with the sloppiness - but I think they might be on to something. Thanks for the insight though